# Store arrays on a key searchable redis list

Tags: arrays, data-structures, redis, set

I'm new with Redis, and I'm trying to figure out witch is the best way to store pairs string:string[] in only one set or data structure in redis.

The idea will be to be able to search for the string key in an structure like this:

```
set:{
   "one":["a","b],
   "two":["c","d]
}
```

So ill would get an array if a look for a string key.

Comment: Because I want to use it as an index. And I already have two of them built that way.  I would like to do something like zrank set one, and then with the position, get an array. Is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the array of strings into a string, and take the new string as the value of your original key.

For your example, if I serialize the array by joining elements with a `:`, you can have two pairs of strings:

```
key: "one", value: "a:b"
key: "two", value: "c:d"
```

Then you can set these key-value pairs into Redis, e.g. `SET one a:b`.

When you retrieve the value from Redis, deserialize the value to get the array.

Comment: Thats not what I want. I want one and two in the same set

Comment: You CANNOT do that. However, if you do need them in the same *container*, NOT a `SET`, you can save both key-value pairs into a `HASH`: `HSET container one a:b`, `HSET container two c:d`

Comment: I agree with @for_stack's approach. Use a Hash, each field is your "key". I'd use MessagePack (or JSON) to serialize the array and store it as the value.

Comment: This 2 yrs ago, but I don't see any indication of a change.  Packing and serializing / parsing a hash (from/into the array you wanted in the first place) in a web-scripting language is slower than a DB-lookup in many/most cases - removing the purpose of the memory-based storage.  Or am I missing something?  Maybe there is a superior memory based tool which can cache and retrieve arrays?

Comment: @JosephK Maybe you want to try [redis-protobuf](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf), which is a Redis Module. You can define any nested data structures with Protobuf, e.g. a hash of array, and read/write the data structure with this module.